# Using picasso for loading images asynchronously

Tags: android, picasso

I want to load the images while recycler view is scrolling. For this I am using picasso.

I am creating a file to store the image inside the picasso. But it is not getting created. When I tried to debug I found that it dose not run the code after .into(), it directly goes down to the complesPreferences code.

So as complexPreferences left null it is giving the null pointer exception.

contactAdapter :

```
    public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedListRowHolder> {


    private List<FeedItem> feedItemList;

    private Context mContext;

    public ContactAdapter(Context context, List<FeedItem> feedItemList) {
        this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public FeedListRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,null);
        FeedListRowHolder mh = new FeedListRowHolder(v);

        return mh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FeedListRowHolder feedListRowHolder, int i) {
        final FeedItem feedItem = feedItemList.get(i);
        Log.e("Imagename",""+"http://xesoftwares.co.in/contactsapi/profile_images/85368a5bbd6cffba8a3aa202a80563a2.jpg");//+feedItem.getThumbnail());


       Picasso.with(mContext).load(feedItem.getprofileImage())
                .error(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_24dp)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_24dp)
                .resize(100,100)
                .into(new Target() {

                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                        try {
                            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
                            File myDir = new File(root +"/Contact");

                            if (!myDir.exists()) {
                                myDir.mkdirs();
                            }

                           // String name = new Date().toString();
                            String name = new Date().toString()+".jpg";
                          File  myDir1 = new File(myDir, name);

                            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myDir1);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

                            ImageFilePath imageFilePath1=new ImageFilePath(myDir1);
                            ComplexPreferences complexPreferences112 = ComplexPreferences.getComplexPreferences(mContext, "mypref112", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            complexPreferences112.putObject("imageFilePath1", imageFilePath1);
                            Log.e("user2", "" + imageFilePath1);
                            complexPreferences112.commit();
                            out.flush();
                            out.close();
                        } catch(Exception e){
                            // some action
                        }
                    }

                    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                    }

                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                    }
                });

       ComplexPreferences complexPreferences112 = ComplexPreferences.getComplexPreferences(mContext, "mypref112", mContext.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ImageFilePath imageFilePath1= complexPreferences112.getObject("imageFilePath1", ImageFilePath.class);
        File myDir1=imageFilePath1.getprofile();

       Picasso.with(mContext).load(myDir1).into(feedListRowHolder.thumbnail);

        feedListRowHolder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getTitle()));
        //feedListRowHolder.genre.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getGenre()));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != feedItemList ? feedItemList.size() : 0);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help with this? Why it's not working.. Thank you..

EDIT : I tried like this:

Still its not getting called I think because still getting null pointer exception on complexPreferences.

```
public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedListRowHolder> {


    private List<FeedItem> feedItemList;

    private Context mContext;

    public ContactAdapter(Context context, List<FeedItem> feedItemList) {
        this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public FeedListRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,null);
        FeedListRowHolder mh = new FeedListRowHolder(v);

        return mh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FeedListRowHolder feedListRowHolder, int i) {
        final FeedItem feedItem = feedItemList.get(i);
        Log.e("Imagename",""+"http://xesoftwares.co.in/contactsapi/profile_images/85368a5bbd6cffba8a3aa202a80563a2.jpg");//+feedItem.getThumbnail());


        Target target = new Target () {
            // your code here ...

            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                try {
                    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
                    File myDir = new File(root +"/Contact");

                    if (!myDir.exists()) {
                        myDir.mkdirs();
                    }

                    // String name = new Date().toString();
                    String name = new Date().toString()+".jpg";
                    File  myDir1 = new File(myDir, name);

                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myDir1);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

                    ImageFilePath imageFilePath1=new ImageFilePath(myDir1);
                    ComplexPreferences complexPreferences112 = ComplexPreferences.getComplexPreferences(mContext, "mypref112", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                    complexPreferences112.putObject("imageFilePath1", imageFilePath1);
                    Log.e("user2", "" + imageFilePath1);
                    complexPreferences112.commit();
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    // some action
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            }

        };
        feedListRowHolder.thumbnail.setTag(target);

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(feedItem.getprofileImage())
                .error(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_24dp)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_24dp)
                .resize(100,100)
                .into(target);


       ComplexPreferences complexPreferences112 = ComplexPreferences.getComplexPreferences(mContext, "mypref112", mContext.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ImageFilePath imageFilePath1= complexPreferences112.getObject("imageFilePath1", ImageFilePath.class);

            File myDir1 = imageFilePath1.getprofile();

            Picasso.with(mContext).load(myDir1).into(feedListRowHolder.thumbnail);

        feedListRowHolder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getTitle()));
        //feedListRowHolder.genre.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getGenre()));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != feedItemList ? feedItemList.size() : 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check if any of the callbacks i.e. onBitmapFailed were called? Actually I doubt, that the (probably async) into()-method is silently ignored.

Comment: yes it is getting ignored. But why and how..@everyman

Comment: Maybe you should show your custom View implementing Target Interface and check if it meets requirements mentioned here https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/Target.java#L23 - Maybe someone else knows better...

Comment: @Sid that is not possible it cant be ignored error is somewhere else

Comment: Ha! Did you forgot to add the @Override annotations?

Comment: for onBitmapLoaded() ? ya may be @everyman

Comment: Yes - for all actually!

Comment: but that did not help.. @everyman